# What is the best way to check if the 'Focused' input is the last one in the <li>

Tags: jquery

HTML :

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <ul>    
        <li class="answerFields">
            <input type="text" value="" />
            <input type="text" value="" />
            <input type="text" value="" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

JQUERY :

```
$('.inputfield input').last().live('focus', function() {

    //this is just an example//
    document.write('a');
    ...
});
```

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rayd360/n62GN/2).

I want to be able to check if the input that the user focuses is the last input in the `<li>`

constraints: I cannot change the HTML. The number of inputs will also be increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. `$('.inputfield input').last().live(...)` won't work. `.live()` has to immediately follow the selector:

   > Chaining methods is not supported. For example, `$("a").find(".offsite, .external").live( ... );` is not valid and does not work as expected.
2. `document.write('a')` will replace the current document. But I guess you only have it for testing. Still, you should be using `console.log` or append to the body.

To answer the question:

You can just check whether there are any following `input` elements or not:

```
if($(this).nextAll('input').length === 0) {
    // this is the last input element
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the following selector if you only want to bind to the last input element:

```
$('.inputfield input:last').live(...);
```

Make sure [you know about the many disadvantages of `.live()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Consider to use [`.delegate()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`.on()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

You might also want to consider listening to the `focus` event instead of `click`. The focus can be changed with the tab key as well.

Answer (score 3):

is this what you're looking for:

```
$('.answerFields input:last-of-type').live('click', function() {
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery next() to see if there is a sibling (the last input will not have one)

http://jsfiddle.net/7vEy2/

edit: code

```
$('li > input').live('focus', function() {
    var that = $(this);

    if (that.next().length === 0) {
        alert('last one gained focus!');        
    } else {
        alert('nope');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post your code in your answer instead of a link to a fiddle. Fiddles eventually expire and we want future visitors to this question to benefit from your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

this works regardless of how many inputs per li or how many lis you have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var hoverIn = function()
{
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
}
var hoverOut = function()
{
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
}

var init = function()
{
    var liEls = $('.answerFields');
    for( i=0; i < liEls.length; i++)
    {
        $(liEls[i]).children('input:text').last().hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);
    }
}
window.onload = init;
</script>

<form>
<fieldset>
    <ul>    
        <li class="answerFields">
            <input type="text" value=""/>
            <input type="text" value=""/>
            <input type="text" value=""/>
        </li>
        <li class="answerFields">
            <input type="text" value=""/>
            <input type="text" value=""/>
            <input type="text" value=""/>
            <input type="text" value=""/>
        </li>
        <li class="answerFields">
            <input type="text" value=""/>
            <input type="text" value=""/>
        </li>
        <li class="answerFields">
            <input type="text" value=""/>
            <input type="text" value=""/>
            <input type="text" value=""/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `delegate` to monitor the parent. Then check if it is last input. Finally do something if so.

http://jsfiddle.net/n62GN/4/

```
$('.answerFields').delegate('input[type=text]', 'click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
       $(this).val('last');        
    }
});​
```

Live is deprecated so you should get used to delegate instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$('li.answerFields').on('click','input:last', function() {    
     //document.write('a');
     alert('a');
 });​
```

I see in your fiddle you are using an older version of jQuery, in that case you can use delegate like this

```
$('li.answerFields').delegate('input:last','click', function() {    
     //document.write('a');
     alert('a');
 });​
```